# Proliant server ML 370 G4 RAM upgraade

Tags: memory, hp, hp-proliant

can we use ECC non-registered RAM 667MHz on HP Proliant ML 370 G4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server requires and expects registered RAM. Use the proper RAM for the system...

The [HP ProLiant ML370 G4](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/12029_na/12029_na.html) is an 8 or 9 year-old server with **[extremely-limited RAM upgrade options](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/12029_na/12029_na.html#Memory)**. It's time to retire that server, if possible...

If you do opt to upgrade, RAM needs to be added in pairs and the only modules available to you are **512MB**, **1GB**, and **2GB** in capacity. There are eight slots. The server takes a maximum of 16GB of RAM.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the hyperlink, it is for SOHO Fileserver.